# How do I use the sqs-message-driven-channel-adapter in spring-integration-aws

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-aws

**EDIT**: Here is a gist showing my log.  It appears that there is  `ReceiveMessage` and then a `preSend` on `inputChannel`:

https://gist.github.com/louisalexander/04e7d95835521efdd15455c98075e2ea

Apologies for being so dense, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly make use of the `sqs-message-driven-channel-adapter`

In my context file, I am configuring it as such:

```
<int-aws:sqs-message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="my-message-driven-adapter" sqs="sqs" queues="some-queue-of-mine"
    max-number-of-messages="5" visibility-timeout="200" wait-time-out="10"
    send-timeout="2000" channel="inputChannel" />
```

I observe that messages are properly making it into `some-queue-of-mine` (by removing the above bit of code and sending messages to the queue).  I then restart my server, enabling the message driven adapter and I observe that all the messages are consumed from the queue, but where did they go? :-/

My expectation was that the messages would be funneled into a `DirectChannel` named `inputChannel`:

```
<int:channel id="inputChannel"/>
```

That I have a `service-activator` consuming from as follows:

```
<int:service-activator ref="myConsumer"
    method='execute' input-channel="inputChannel" output-channel="outputChannel">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        ...
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>
```

But of course, I am never seeing `myConsumer` get invoked.  I imagine my understanding of how the `MessageProducer` mechanism works is inadequate.  Can someone please correct my thinking by providing a trivial example of XML wiring?

Comment: I suggest you to switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` category and try to figure out what's going on in logs. Or just share that with us when you think your messages must go to the `inputChannel`.

Comment: I have edited my question to supply a gist showing the o.s.integration debug

Comment: Sorry, there is no one in your question.

Comment: The gist is at the top, here it is again: https://gist.github.com/louisalexander/04e7d95835521efdd15455c98075e2ea

Comment: And? What don't you like? There is even `ServiceActivator for` log message meaning that some subscriber on the `inputChannel` is invoked. Try to comment out that `<int:service-activator ref="myConsumer">` and see what's going on. Right now your words don't fit to  the logs: the message is received and handled by some subscriber on the `inputChannel`.

Comment: inputChannel is invoked, but I am not seeing myConsumer get activated.  There are no additional subscribers to inputChannel, but *someone* is consuming the message.  This is what I don't completely understand.

Comment: Just make a search around your config to be sure who consumes your messages

Comment: Indeed the logging says that the inputChannel is being consumed by the ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@493f49cd]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135804/discussion-between-louis-alexander-and-artem-bilan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Logs the message is consumed by the `handler.AbstractMessageHandler (AbstractMessageHandler.java:115) - ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@493f49cd]`. Although that might be a fully different story.

`SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` can be supplied with the `errorChannel` to handle downstream exceptions. By default it is only logged.

The message sent from that adapter is like:

```
return new GenericMessage<>(message.getBody(), new SqsMessageHeaders(messageHeaders));
```

Where that `message.getBody()` is `String`. See `QueueMessageUtils.createMessage()`.

So, be sure that your `service-activator` accepts that `String` as a paylaod and not any other type.

Comment: This is exactly what I had observed.  The message I am trying to deposit on SQS using  int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter is the string "com.my.class.MyObjectMessaged@feedface".  So it appears that I need to  use a Transformer in front of the int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter to properly convert it into a string, and then perform the opposite transformation on the input from int-aws:sqs-message-driven-channel-adapter.  Let me work on this and then I will post the solution and accept your answer.

Comment: Consider to use `ObjectToJsonTransformer` and its opposite - `JsonToObjectTransformer`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#_json_transformers